# Android TextView BG opacity?

Tags: android, textview

I want to change the opacity of my bg in my textview, not the text only.

How to do this?

As I mentioned, it's not a duplicate question, because I don't want to change my textview opacity, i want to change my tv bg opacity, so it's a different question.

I have an image behind my text, that I want to change.

Thanks!

Comment: Use as background a color with some alpha... i.e.: **#8f00** is half-transparent red (not really half - it is `88` while half is `80` - just to use the short color form).

Comment: But I can't use a color for background, because I'm using an image, it's part of my UI design.

Comment: So simply make the image transparent in your favourite graphic editor.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility its applicate alpha to image in Photoshop or something similar.

Another possibility its define image in xml source, and applicate this image to edittext background across style.xml Something like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/your_drawble"
    android:alpha="77">
</bitmap>
```

Another possibility its use this (values between 0-255):

```
textView.getBackground().setAlpha(51);
```

Comment: No need to use style.xml to apply a Bitmap Drawable. Anyway, +1. Good idea.

Comment: I like to use the styles.xml ;)